# How do I create an ios table with first column fixed and the next column, rows horizontally scrollable to 1

Tags: ios, uitableview

In iOS, I basically want to display images as follows:

I need 2 columns in a table. The image in the first column is fixed, and in the second column the rows  should have  horizontal scrolling to scroll the images. On selecting an image it should go to another view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1), and the likes of it.

For details about how to have fixed first image, there is no better way than [starting from scratch, going by the books](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        
        //Normar cell
        
    }else if(indexPath.row == 1){
        
        //add ScrollVeiw
    }
}
```

and for the height of the cell

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        //height for scrollview
        
    }
}
```